# how do i create a variable from another variable name?

Tags: php, variables, loops

ok...in php how do i do this? given the following scenario:

```
// array of letters
var $letters = array('a', 'b', 'c');
// loop through array and create empty arrays with names like $a, $b, $c
foreach($letters as $letter) {
    var $$letter = array();
}
```

Comment: Is an array not better for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was almost correct.  You just need to remove 'var' on the 2nd and fifth lines.

```
// array of letters
$letters = array('a', 'b', 'c');
// loop through array and create empty arrays with names like $a, $b, $c
foreach($letters as $letter) {
    $$letter = array();
}
```

This works correctly (as you described).  I tested it.

More [information on variable variables here](http://au.php.net/language.variables.variable).

*As an aside, I would recommend against using eval() in your PHP.*

Comment: You may want to look into turning on display_errors in your php.ini (on your development machine) - needs to be done that way to display parse errors.  Also, the PHP command line interface can syntax check (ie calls it lint) - I have that integrated into my text editor/IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to do this.  Wanting to use variable variables is usually a sign of a failure to understand data structures and/or excessive cleverness.  If you really want to do this, you could say something like...

```
extract(array_fill_keys($letters, array()));
```

...but it would be best if you didn't.  Using nested arrays is probably a much better idea - especially since you can just say `$nested['a'][] = 5` and PHP will append the value to the array, creating one if nothing is there.  Alternately, you could just say `$varname['key'] = 123` and, again, PHP will auto-create the array for you.

Comment: variable variables are actually very useful and powerful, and I've certainly wanted them over arrays multiple times.  Example: using the array of columns that comes back SQL to populate a Model instance.

Comment: seanmonstar - you mean like extract() http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php ?

Comment: no, i dont mean like extract. extract just fills the current scope with variables.  variable variables allows me to assign the values from an array as properties of a model instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the eval() function:  [Eval](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp)

Comment: I would recommend against using eval.  There is no situation in which eval() is the only solution, or even the best solution, and suggesting its use here is ill-advised and in my opinion, strange.