# PHP Variables from another var

Tags: php, variables

This may sound confusing:

```
$myVar = "Helloooo!";
$text = "myVar";
```

How could i call `$myVar` from just the fact `$text` is filled with the variable name, perhaps this ? (it doesnt work though)

```
echo $($text);
```

Comment: It may be best to avoid this. It's very fragile and error prone. You can achieve the same results using an array, like setting $a[$myVar] and using it instead of $$myVar.

Comment: duplicate of [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php), [how do i create a variable from another variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664606/how-do-i-create-a-variable-from-another-variable-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a feature called "[variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)", that works exactly like you need it to.

You can use it almost like you posted, but without the brackets:

```
echo $$text;
```

The best notation is using curly braces however, as that removes ambiguities when dealing with arrays.

```
echo ${$text};
```