# PHP string == name of array?

Tags: php

If I have an array named `$myArray` how can I get a reference to it from a string of the same name `myArray`. I tried:

```
eval('myArray');
```

But that gave me an error.

Comment: Why not store the array in a dictionary? Given that dictonaries exist in PHP, dunno

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: Arrays are the only datastructure in PHP but they can be used as dictionaries too.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks, I am not familiar with PHP as you might have noticed :)

Comment: duplicate of [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php), [how do i create a variable from another variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664606/how-do-i-create-a-variable-from-another-variable-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be

```
${"myArray"}
```

or if the string is contained in another variable:

```
$a = "myArray";
$$a // <- points to $myArray
```

[**Read about variable variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Very useful. But can be very confusing if used improperly. Thanks!

Comment: Also I figured out...just to make your list complete in a class it is $this->$a